# How to combine Image-based recommender and Collborative recommender?

Tags: recommender-system

I am making a hybrid recommender of two models: Collaborative and Image. Hybrid will receive 2 additional percentage parameters to calculate rating between user and item. For example, to predict rating for user 1, item 1, it would be 0.4*collabModel.predict(1,1) + 0.6*imageModel.predict(1,1)

The problem is that when I searched online, no one calculated image-based ratings, so I think the way I did it was wrong.

Can anyone suggest me a way? The purpose of doing this is to show the improvement between using Collaborative alone and when using Collab and Image-based in combination.